# Add UiStepper programmatically inside cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

how do I add a UIStepper to every cell of my UITableView programmatically?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to add the UIStepper to each cell as a subview in tableView:cellForRowIndexAtPath in your TableViewController. For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       UIStepper* stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] init];
       stepper.frame = CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 10);
       [cell.contentView addSubview: stepper];
   }  

   return cell; 
}
```

This will add a stepper to the right-hand side of each cell in your table.